# Can an ideal of a ring be an ideal of a subring/superring too?

Tags: ring-theory

Let $R\neq S$ be rings with unity. Let $R$ be a subring (sharing the same unity) of $S.$ Let $\{0\}\neq K\subseteq R.$ Is it possible that $K$ is at the same time an ideal in $R$ and an ideal in $S?$

Comment: Should your subrings have unity? Because some people don't care about my friend unity.

Comment: 0$\,\,\,\,\,\,$

Comment: My mistake. I didn't read the question properly. And I meant, for some kernels are subrings as well. For, them, subrings need not have unity, even if rings are unital.

Comment: @MP I thought you posted by accident but I see your comment was voted up twice. All I see in your comment is "o". Is my computer not displaying it properly?

Comment: @ymar $\{0\}$ is an ideal in every ring.

Comment: Oh right. I will correct my question.

Comment: You might search around for examples of "conductors" of ring extensions.

Comment: An other trivial example is when $R=S$. It's a very good question!

Comment: @emiliocba you're right. I should be more careful. I'm correcting the question.

Comment: @DylanMoreland Could you please give me a reference? I don't know what conductors are.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let $O$ be a valuation domain of Krull dimension >1 and let $p\neq 0$ be a non-maximal prime of $O$. Then every proper ideal of the localization $O_p$ is a proper ideal of $O$ itself.

To show this it suffices to prove the inclusion $pO_p\subset O$: It then follows that $pO_p=p$ and since $pO_p$ is maximal, every ideal of $O_p$ is contained in $p$ and thus in $O$.

So assume that some element $\frac{a}{b}$, $a\in p$, $b\in O\setminus p$ is not in $O$. Since $O$ is a valuation domain one concludes $\frac{b}{a}\in O$, hence $b\in p$, a contradiction.

Answer (score 7):

Consider $S = \mathbb Q[x]$, the rational polynomials in one unknown.  Define $R = \mathbb Z + \mathbb x\mathbb Q[x]$.  Now $K = x\mathbb Q[x]$ is an ideal in both rings.

Comment: More generally, given any graded ring $R=\oplus R_i$, and a graded subring $S=\oplus S_i$, such that, for some $n$, $\forall i\geq n: S_i=R_i$.  Then $\oplus_{i\geq n} R_i$ is an ideal in $R$ and $S$.

Comment: Thank you very much. I will accept Hagen's answer though, because yours has many upvotes anyway, and I think both should be on top.

Comment: Yes, I upvoted @CruiskeenLawn because that was interesting to me.

Answer (score 7):

Let $S$ be the set of sequences in $\mathbb{Z}/\mathbb{2Z}$, which is a ring with term-wise addition and multiplication. The set of sequences that are eventually constant is a subring R (it contains $1=(1,1,1,...)$). The set of sequences that are eventually zero is an ideal $K \subset R$ such that $K \lhd S$.

A simpler example works with $S=\mathbb{Z}/\mathbb{2Z} \times\mathbb{Z}/\mathbb{2Z} \times \mathbb{Z}/\mathbb{2Z}$, $R$ being the subring with the last two entries the same, and $K$ being the ideal with the last two entries zero.

Comment: These are great examples. Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

If $K$ is an ideal in $S$, then it's an ideal in $R$ (by definition).

**Example:**
$$
K=\left\{\left(\begin{array}{cc}0&b\\ 0&c\end{array}\right):b,c\in\mathbb R\right\}
$$
is a left-ideal in
$
R=\left\{\left(\begin{array}{cc}a&b\\ 0&c\end{array}\right):a,b\in\mathbb R\right\}
$
and in $S=M_2(\mathbb R)$.

Conversely, it's not true that if $K$ is an ideal in $R$ then it is neccesarly an ideal in $S$.

**Counterexample:** 
$$
K=2\mathbb Z\subset R=\mathbb Z\subset S=\mathbb Z[\sqrt{2}]=\{a+b\sqrt{2}:a,b\in \mathbb Z\}.
$$
Clearly, $2\mathbb Z$ is not an ideal in $\mathbb Z[\sqrt{2}]$.

Comment: But this doesn't answer my question! Of course an ideal in a subring doesn't **have** to be an ideal in the superring. I'm asking if it **can** be.

Comment: It's a nice example now, but still not to the question I asked. I was asking about ideals, not left ideals. But this is something worth noticing, still. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Another example: $\mathbb Z$ embeds into $\mathbb Z[x]/(2 x)$, then $(2)$ is an ideal in both rings.